# Web Dynpro Action on Button

Tags: abap, webdynpro

There is some kind of Shopping Cart in which you have Product positions. 
There is a Button in web dynpro which is supposed to copy the text from the Inputfield from one position to the others.

When I click one of the positions, and enter a text in the inputfield and click on copy to all other positions - it doesn't copy. 
Only if I click the button twice it copies the position to the others. What am I doing wrong? 
I'm not a web dynpro expert.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, take the [tour], and read [ask]

Comment: Give the code and WD layout

Answer (score 0):

Could be an IE bug or some problem in the code.

You can check the **onAction** property of your button and also check if there's any loop in the events that could probably cause this "only for the second click" behavior.

Please share your Controller/View code so we can provide a complete answer.